# How does the str_replace function work?

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I'm trying to understand the `str_replace` function.

Code:

```
$a = array(1,8,7,5);
$b = array(3,7,11,6);
$str = '879';
$c = str_replace($a, $b , $str);
echo $c;
```

Output:

> 11119

I don't understand the output. Can someone explain how the `str_replace` function works?

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Well the answers are clear. In case your desired result for 879 is 7119 then you can use `strtr` https://3v4l.org/AVemR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace` replaces pair of values from provided arrays `$a`, `$b`.
And does it in order, so `str_replace($a, $b , $str)` means:

```
replace 1 to 3,
then replace 8 to 7,
then replace 7 to 11
and finally replace 5 to 6.
```

So, let's go:

- input `879`, replace 1 to 3, output `879`
- input `879`, replace 8 to 7, output `779`
- input `779`, replace 7 to 11, output `11119`
- input `11119`, replace 5 to 6, output `11119`

Comment: ThanksI didn't see the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, you have `879` :

1. 8 => 7

So you have now `779`

2. 7 => 11

Now you have `11119`

You didn't provided any replacement for 9 or 11 so your returned number is `11119`